# How to enable grails for Intellij Community 2016.2.5

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

I just installed intellij community 2016.2.5 in mac, and tried to create a grails project. It does not show grails as an option, but shows Groovy, Gradle, Griffin.

I went to the [intellij grails page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/grails.html) and it says:

> Also, make sure that the Grails plugin is enabled in IntelliJ IDEA. The plugin is bundled with IntelliJ IDEA and is activated by default

Then, I tried to enable the plugin, or find in repositories, but didn't find any, only a Grails Tools, that is not from jetbrains, and after a install and restart, still don't show anything.

[image]

Anyone has used this lastest version with Grails? Has any solution or workaround to make it works? Should I download some older version?

Thanks.

Comment: I asked in grails-community slack, and got this: community edition doesn't come with the grails plugin, though you can create a grails project and import it as a gradle project in intellij and get most of the functionality. I will try and post a full answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how I import a Grails 3 app into community edition:

First use SDKMAN to get grails - http://sdkman.io/install.html

```
sdk use grails 3.2.1
grails create-app mytestapp
```

Then import existing project, select the `build.gradle` file

- Check `Use Auto Import`
- Use gradle wrapper

You can run it by using the `bootRun` gradle task in the gradle toolbar or going to the `Application.groovy` file and running the `main()` method.

To see some of the run configs in action you can watch https://www.ociweb.com/products/grails/grails-quickcast-6-developing-grails-3-applications-with-intellij-idea/ - Though I would recomend running gradle from inside intellij, not via the command line. That was just to show how remote debugging works.

With community you lose some features, but it does work well.